# Sending a recorded audio file from one activity to another

Tags: java, android

I am currently recording a message and initialising the objects in one fragment. I'd like to pass it to my main activity. However, I can pass an image between fragments using this:

```
    public void captureImage() {
    mCamera.captureImage(new CameraKitEventCallback<CameraKitImage>() {
        @Override
        public void callback(CameraKitImage cameraKitImage) {
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setBitmapToSend(cameraKitImage.getBitmap());
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).openDisplayImageFragment();
        }
    });
}
```

I have initialised a media recorder within the class. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If the Main Activity is hosting your fragment, then you can send the data from fragment to its parent Activity by - Interface callbacks or creating a public method in your Activity.

Since you can always get the reference to the parent Activity using getActivity(), you can cast it and pass values to the public method. Eg:

```
myActivity=(MainActivity) getActivity ();
myActivity.receiveAudio(<"Pass the data as object or in byte[]">);
```

2. Sending data from a fragment to another activity require to add Intent extras. Eg:

   myIntent.putExtra("myKey",<"Place your object or byte array">);
   startActivity(myActivity);

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: You can convert your audio data into byte array and send it. If this helped, please mark it as an answer so that others can also benefit from it.